# I am unable to sort the 'last names' in the file by alphabetical order: I get Abort trap: 6

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort, swap, abort

I am writing a program that is required to read two files (NamesIDs.txt and marks.txt) and needs to print the records in the NamesIDs.txt file as is and also print the same records sorted by alphabetical order (by the last name). I am able to do the first part but the second part gives 'Abort trap: 6)
The files can be found here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2B0-_NdCDikSEVjX3ZYU0tpQTQ?usp=sharing

Here is my code:

```
/*   This program assumes that
  names and IDs data file (location and name) is passed as the first argument
 and marks data files is passed as the second argument
 */


#define MAXRECORDS 100
#define MAXNAMELENGTH 15
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//Define structure to hold student data
struct StudentRecord
{
    char FirstNames[MAXNAMELENGTH];
    char LastNames[MAXNAMELENGTH];
    int IDNums;
    int Marks;

};



int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    struct StudentRecord SRecords[MAXRECORDS];
        int numrecords, nummarks, recordnum, r;
        char Temp[1];

    //Read in Names and ID data
    FILE * NamesIDsDataFile;
    if((NamesIDsDataFile = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Can't read from file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    numrecords=0;
        while (fscanf(NamesIDsDataFile,"%s%s%d",&(SRecords[numrecords].FirstNames[0]),
                            &(SRecords[numrecords].LastNames[0]),
                            &(SRecords[numrecords].IDNums)) != EOF) {
      numrecords++;
    }

    fclose(NamesIDsDataFile);

    //Read in marks data
    FILE * MarksDataFile;
    if((MarksDataFile = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Can't read from file %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }
    nummarks=0;
    while(fscanf(MarksDataFile,"%d",&(SRecords[nummarks].Marks)) != EOF) {
        nummarks++;
    }

    fclose(MarksDataFile);

    //Print out data as read in
    for(recordnum=0;recordnum<numrecords;recordnum++){
        printf("%s %s %d %d\n",SRecords[recordnum].FirstNames,SRecords[recordnum].LastNames,SRecords[recordnum].IDNums, SRecords[recordnum].Marks);
    }
    printf("A total of %d records printed.\n",numrecords);

    while (recordnum>0){
        numrecords=0;
        while (SRecords[numrecords].LastNames[0] != EOF ){
            r= strcmp(SRecords[numrecords].LastNames, SRecords[numrecords+1].LastNames);
            if (r>0){
                strcpy(Temp, SRecords[numrecords].LastNames);
                strcpy(SRecords[numrecords].LastNames, SRecords[numrecords+1].LastNames);
                strcpy(SRecords[numrecords+1].LastNames, Temp);
            }
            numrecords++;

        }
        recordnum--;
    }

    printf("\nTHE SORTED NAMES ARE AS FOLLOWS\n");
    for(recordnum=0;recordnum<numrecords;recordnum++){
        printf("%s %s %d %d\n",SRecords[recordnum].FirstNames,SRecords[recordnum].LastNames,SRecords[recordnum].IDNums, SRecords[recordnum].Marks);
    }
    printf("A total of %d records printed.\n",numrecords);




    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Help would be HIGHLY appreciated. THANK YOU!

Comment: There are at  least two problems: 1.) `char Temp[1]` -> `char Temp[MAXNAMELENGTH]`. 2.)  `while (SRecords[numrecords].LastNames[0] != EOF)` will not work as expected, EOF is not stored in the last name. Even if it was, the condition shall be `while (SRecords[numrecords+1].LastNames[0] != EOF)`  or better `while (SRecords[numrecords+1].LastNames[0] != 0)`

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the command line argument(s) actually exist

Comment: regarding: `while(fscanf(MarksDataFile,"%d",&(SRecords[nummarks].Marks)) != EOF)`  there are other conditions besides EOF.  Suggest check for a positive/successful condition: `while(fscanf(MarksDataFile,"%d",&(SRecords[nummarks].Marks)) == 1)`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Can't read from file %s\n", argv[2]);` when displaying an error message, it should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error indication comes from a system function, also display the related text.  Suggest:   `perror( "fopen failed" );`

Comment: regarding: `while (fscanf(NamesIDsDataFile,"%s%s%d",
            &(SRecords[numrecords].FirstNames[0]),
            &(SRecords[numrecords].LastNames[0]),
            &(SRecords[numrecords].IDNums)) != EOF)`  as stated in an earlier comment, check for a positive/successful condition.  Suggest: `while (fscanf(NamesIDsDataFile,"%s%s%d",
            &(SRecords[numrecords].FirstNames[0]),
            &(SRecords[numrecords].LastNames[0]),
            &(SRecords[numrecords].IDNums)) == 3)`

Comment: what happens when the `nummarks` and `numrecords` do not match?

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, using the '%s' input/format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is on less than the length of the input buffer.  Remember that that specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input.  If the length of the input were to exceed (sizeof(inputbuffer)) the result is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: what happens if/when the input file holds more than `MAXRECORDS`?

Comment: regarding: `struct StudentRecord SRecords[MAXRECORDS];`  it is usually not a good idea to place huge amounts of data on the stack.  Suggest: `struct StudentRecord *SRecords = malloc( MAXRECORDS * sizeof( struct StudentRecord) );` so the data is kept on the heap and all the stack contains is a pointer to the data.  then adjust the rest of the code accordingly.

Comment: regarding: `strcpy(SRecords[numrecords].LastNames, SRecords[numrecords+1].LastNames);` and `strcpy(SRecords[numrecords+1].LastNames, Temp);`  on the last record, this could be accessing beyond the upper bound of the array.  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Even if it does not exceed the array upper bound, these two statements will be accessing uninitialized data

Comment: regarding: `while (SRecords[numrecords].LastNames[0] != EOF )`  NONE of the data will contain EOF, ever.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting algorithm is not correct.

Here is an example of the algorithm for a `bubble` sort.

There are other varieties of sort algorithms AND there is the `qsort()` library function, those prototype is exposed in the header file: `stdlib.h`.

for the example code, 
    'c' is a local counter
    'd' is a local counter
    'n' is number of entries to be sorted
    'array[]' is the entries to be sorted
    'swap' is to have the same type as one entry in 'array[]'

```
for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
{
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
        if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
        {
            swap       = array[d];
            array[d]   = array[d+1];
            array[d+1] = swap;
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to modify the above, perhaps by using `strcmp()` in place of `(array[d] > array[d+1])` to handle your specific data.